# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'

Tags: jquery

What's wrong with this?

```
$('tbody').on('click', '.expand', function () {
    var $button = $(this);
    var chart = $button.closest('tr').attr('chart');
    $('tr[chart="' + chart + '"]').slideDown('fast', function () {
        $button.text('-').removeClass('expand').addClass('contract');
    });
});
```

Chrome tells me `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'`

**Update:**

Ok so I decided to upgrade. I upgraded to 1.10 because I may well have IE7/8 users, but every page gives this error now: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined`

Will try an earlier version.

**Resolution:**

Version 1.7.2 works great :)

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: do you have prototype or any other libraries along with jQuery

Comment: Actually the HTML is badly formatted - I'll try that first...

Comment: But no other libraries and jQuery is version 1.4.1

Comment: .on() doesn't exist in jQuery 1.4.1

Comment: [Version added: 1.7](http://api.jquery.com/on/) Why are you using a more than 3 year old version anyway?

Comment: Erm - nostalgic reasons?? Sorry no good answer for that, other than that is the version added by VS. Will retry with 1.7.

Comment: you need to use live() in that case `$('tbody .expand').live('click', function(){})`

Comment: If you have the chance to update, go straight to 1.10 or 2.0. There's no reason to use an outdated version.

Comment: Update jQuery, or use [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) - *"As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method. For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to use event delegation. More information on event binding and delegation is in the .on() method."*

Comment: @billyonecan [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) was added in version 1.4.2, the OP is using 1.4.1

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Ah, well spotted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend updating to newest version if it is possible.

If not use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$('tbody .expand').live('click', function(){})
```